# Nginx Subdirectory - Location Path Added to Root

Tags: nginx

Working on accessing a wordpress install in a subdirectory off my main webroot.

My main website is stored in `/var/www/example.com/htdocs`
My wordpress install is stored in `/var/www/wordpress.example.com/wordpress`

I want to be able to access my wordpress install from `example.com/blog`

```
server {
    ...
    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs;
    ...

    location ^~ /blog {
        root /var/www/wordpress.example.com/wordpress;
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting a 404 where `/blog` is added to the root also (which isn't desired).

> "/var/www/wordpress.example.com/wordpress/blog/index.php" is not found

Notice how the root shows both `/wordpress` and `/blog`. My desire would be for it only to show `/wordpress`. I want it to be accessible from `/blog`, but `/blog` should not be part of the root, because it doesn't exist.

Could you help me resolve this?

Comment: you need to use `alias` not `root` in the location http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer that @Drifter104 is correct, i just want to add an explanation. 
You are wrong using the directive, you should be using alias directive instead of root. 
If you are using root, the requested_uri(location value) will be added to file path. In your case, if the request_uri(location value) /blog, nginx will search the file path in `/var/www/wordpress.example.com/wordpress+/blog`. But if you using alias, the file path that nginx will search is not based on location value. Here is the nginx documentation http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias.